# Subset df based on Shiny input + lat and lng radius

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I'm trying to build a shiny app that will render a geom_line plot with two different time series, one of them is price of my apartments to choose from a SelectInput, the second line in the plot should be the price of apartments of which lat and lng should be between new_latitude and new_longitude from the first input, aggregated by day so that the end result is just one continuous line. In this plot the x is day of the year and the y is average price. The input should only be my apartments

This is my df head()

```
df<-structure(list(unitcode = c("23986", "23986", "23986", "23986", 
"23986", "23986"), lat = c(45.44991, 45.44991, 45.44991, 45.44991, 
45.44991, 45.44991), lng = c(9.17597, 9.17597, 9.17597, 9.17597, 
9.17597, 9.17597), bedrooms = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), maxoccupancytotal = c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), day_of_year = c(55L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 
110L), avg_price = c(190L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L), past_future = c("past", 
"past", "past", "past", "future", "future"), new_latitude = c(49.9415829000532, 
49.9415829000532, 49.9415829000532, 49.9415829000532, 49.9415829000532, 
49.9415829000532), new_longitude = c(15.578627910762, 15.578627910762, 
15.578627910762, 15.578627910762, 15.578627910762, 15.578627910762
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is what I got so far, I'm missing the whole part of summarising and filtering based on lat and lng because quite frankly I'm relatively new to R and totally new to Shiny and don't even know where to start

```
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("darkly"),

#Header
h1("Cohort Health Check", align = "center"),

selectInput(
    inputId = "unitcode",
    label = "Select unit",
    choices = unique(df$unitcode),
    selected = "23986"
  ),


plotlyOutput("plot", height = "650px")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    df%>%
      filter(unitcode == input$unitcode) %>%
      ggplot(aes(day_of_year, avg_price)) +
      geom_line(aes(color = past_future))+ 
      scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,2000,25),labels = dollar)+
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,365,7))+
      scale_color_manual(values=c( "black", "red"))+
      theme_economist()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You had to add the `ggplotly` function before your `ggplot`, because you are rendering with `plotlyOutput`:

```
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("darkly"),

                #Header
                h1("Cohort Health Check", align = "center"),

                selectInput(
                  inputId = "unitcode",
                  label = "Select unit",
                  choices = unique(df$unitcode),
                  selected = "23986"
                ),


                plotlyOutput("plot", height = "650px")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly( df%>%
      filter(unitcode == input$unitcode) %>%
      ggplot(aes(day_of_year, avg_price, group = past_future)) +
      geom_line(aes(color = past_future))+ 
      scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,200,1))+
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,365,7))+
      scale_color_manual(values=c( "black", "red"))+
      theme_economist() )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Good luck with your Shiny!  :D

Comment: not sure this is relevant, the code i added above works fine. what it lacks is a filter to work on lat and lng, the rendering itself as i said works already